# Finding (and choosing) A Tripod

Tags: equipment-recommendation, tripod

Here is my dilemma and question:

I have a Nikon D5100 and I am looking to buy a tripod. However I commute by bus and walk a lot so I need a tripod that is sturdy yet can be portable and light enough that carrying it attached to my bag (or even better inside) would not be an issue.

I have considered a Gorillapod but I am not always close to something that I can prop it on or attach it to and need some height that the Gorillapod doesn't have.

One other consideration is price. I am looking in the 100-150 range but would prefer closer to the 100 dollar range but am flexible.

I have read a lot on here and on other sites and I am a bit lost. There are so many options and so many considerations. I have seen some good tripods but paying 500 dollars is a bit much. Also I would prefer a tripod that is bundled with a head (ball preferably)

I am open and welcome any information, help, and recommendations!

Comment: Quality, portability and price. Choose 2. If you are choosing a tripod within US$150 and fits in your bag, then you know you need to compromise some quality.

Comment: @rockacola - Portability is my number 1, Price is number 2, and quality is number 3. For anyone answering feel free to answer the more expensive models for others looking and something I can look for when I upgrade. =>

Comment: Because portability is such an important requirement I think it's important we know what the longest/heaviest lens you expect to use will be. no point making suggestions for lightweight options when you're shooting with heavyweight lenses, you know?

Comment: @DanWolfgang  I am just getting into DSLRs with a Nikon D5100. Basically I will not be using in large lenses in the near future and at the time will be using the standard kit lens and a 55-200mm lens. When I get to the point of heavyweight lenses I will be further along and will buy a heavy duty tripod.

Comment: I had the same problem as yours a while ago,I found this Dolica Tripod http://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B001D60LG8 fits my needs,I believe that yours will be the same as mine. So keep in your mind that these tripods won't stand wind.This is the only problem I had so far with my tripod, once I was at a top of a mountain and fixed my tripod on the sand (by pushing the metal screws at tripod's legs into the sand) and 2 seconds later the wind throw it away (thank god it didn't fill of the mountain and my camera wasn't on it).If you've wind,put a bag of sands in the hook so it holds still.

Comment: This link has helpful advice on selecting tripods.  [Tripod 101](http://www.prime-junta.net/pont/Pontification/a0099_Tripods_101/_Tripods_101.html)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What are my best options for a tripod for up to $100?](http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/3745/what-are-my-best-options-for-a-tripod-for-up-to-100)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your combination of requirements is a tough one. You essentially want all of the following in a tripod kit (legs and ball head):

- Lightweight;
- Compact when folded;
- Reasonably tall when extended;
- Sturdy enough to bother with; and
- Cheap

If you wanted to pick any two from that list, your options are wide open. Getting all five together is a lot more difficult. As usual, I'm going to recommend going to the B & H Photo and Video website and using their excellent search filter to narrow down the choices. [This link](http://www.bhphotovideo.com/c/search?atclk=Folded%20Length_15-19.9%22&ci=2635&N=4291688436%204293918168%204291757678) will get you a list of tripods with heads for under $250 (the filter doesn't have a lower top price to select) that will fold down to between 15 and 20 inches (38-51cm).

I will personally vouch for both the Benro TravelAngel series and the Cullmann Magic tripod. I know they're at the top end of your range in terms of price, but they're certainly sturdy enough unless you're using a very heavy camera/lens combo, they fold down to a very compact and baggable package, are light enough to carry all of the time without feeling like you're being punished for something, and while they're not something a very tall person would want to use all day, every day, they do get tall enough to be useful.

Undoubtedly, there are equally good choices to be had from other makers. The higher-end Velbons, for instance, are worth it, as are the Vanguards. Induro is also reasonably good, but they don't have a model that is as compact *and* as inexpensive as you want at the same time (you can have either, but not both). I've never laid a hand on the Oben tripods, but they look okay on paper—perhaps somebody else can offer their experience with them?

Unless you are buying used or *really* on sale, though, I'd try to stick to the upper end of your price range. That $50 really makes a difference in the level of performance, and the next significant step up is another $100 or so on top of that. At the sub-$100 level, you're mostly looking at specialty equipment (like the Gorillapod and its kin) or spindly toys that sort of look like tripods.

Comment: Thanks for the information. (BTW the B&H link isn't working.)

Comment: Sorry about that -- it seems to have session info in it (I get the same URL whenever I go there, but it errors out if I use the link directly). Go to http://www.bhphotovideo.com , then to Digital Cameras and Gear, Tripods and Support (under "Carry and Support"), then use the filters on the left-hand side to select **Tripods with heads**, your price range, and folded length (anything that folds down to less than 15" is going to be either too short or too spindly when extended).

Comment: Thanks => The Cullmann Magic looks like it would work, I will see if I can find one in a local store to mess with. =>

Answer (score 0):

I recently bought a Manfrotto 290 MK294, which is an aluminum tripod with a fairly nice ballhead. It was about $130 from B+H. I like it a lot, but I don't know if its light enough for a lot of walking/bus riding.

Obviously, the carbon fiber tripods are a lot lighter, and probably twice the price.

I think this a very personal choice, I'm not sure how well you can decide without actually touching a few. Are there any retail camera stores near you?

Comment: There are and I plan to look more but advice here I find priceless. =>

Comment: I made a trip to B+H's NYC store to see and handle them. I had an excuse, my daughter works in NYC, so it was only a subway ride and a half mile walk, but it still was a special trip.

Comment: I would love to visit that store but it is a bit far from where I am. =>

Answer (score 0):

There's a deal on Woot.com for a Mefoto tripod. Weighs in at 1.8 pounds and compact.

http://electronics.woot.com/offers/mefoto-daytrip-mini-tripods-3-colors

Answer (score 0):

If you want to steady,  rather than hold your camera,  a monopod could be an option?

Then it could also double as a walking stick for you...

Comment: Hello Simon. This is more a comment than an answer.