# How good is the Manfrotto 055XPROB Tripod?

Tags: equipment-recommendation, tripod, ball-head, manfrotto

Planning to buy a tripod for my Nikon D90 and after some analysis i came up with `Manfrotto 055XPROB`, though everything seems quite good but one thing which is a worrying me is its weight.

I saw one similar question [Is the Manfrotto 190XPROB a good first tripod](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/10080/is-the-manfrotto-190xprob-a-good-first-tripod-for-a-student-with-an-entry-level), but for that I also need to do some analysis if the above tripod fits in my budget.

Also, can some one suggest me a good ball head which is best suitable for this tripod.

***Update***

Here is some more information:

1. Budget (Tripod + Ball Head) 300USD
2. Most of my photography is directly related to my traveling, which means generally I shoot landscapes and a bit of nature.

Thanks in advance

Comment: How does this question differ from the other?  We don't know your budget, how you intend to use this tripod (is it too heavy for you? I don't know).  The other question has suggestions of heads for it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is the Manfrotto 190XPROB a good first tripod for a student with an entry-level DSLR?](http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/10080/is-the-manfrotto-190xprob-a-good-first-tripod-for-a-student-with-an-entry-level)

Comment: @MikeW: well i already mentioned that question and only thing was i have not seen that one which will made me to research this and compare with what i have finalized

Comment: Meta discussion again: [What about “review this item please” questions?](http://meta.photo.stackexchange.com/questions/1803/what-about-review-this-item-please-questions)

Comment: @mattdm: well i believe you are right but the question was never intended to compare `Manfrotto 055XPROB` with `190XPROB`. Will try to put it in meta discussion but have to see both of them closely again.

Answer (score 2):

I have the 055CXPRO3 which looks identical except that its carbon fibre.  It's fantastic, and very lightweight.  So if you are after lightweight, consider the CX version.  The main weight comes actually with the head, but a magnesium head also takes care of that (I have the MH054M0-Q2).

The combination of the 055CXPRO3 and MH054M0-Q2 is strong, robust, and for what it is, very very lightweight. I can recommend it.

Comment: the combo you mention won't fit in his budget... I doubt even the XPROB with an aluminium or steel Manfrotto head will fit.

Answer (score 0):

I've a metal 055ProB, so can't comment on the weight of the carbon fibre version. The metal one is very sturdy, solidly built, but large and heavy. Not something I'd take with me on an aircraft or when backpacking (e.g.), it's just too cumbersome (let alone heavy, but the carbon one of course weighs less).
For travel, I bought me a 190 series Manfrotto instead, which is a lot easier to transport when you don't have a car at your disposal (or a sherpa :) ).

Answer (score 0):

You want to buy the [401N Quick Action Strap](http://www.manfrotto.com/ass-quick-action-strap-e401nf) This lets you carry the tripod across your back. Note, this is anything but quick, it takes some practice to put it on and take it off. I guess the "quick" part comes from the fact that you never take it off the tripod. I find it essentially for walking about town for night shoots, or even riding my bike.

Answer (score 0):

I have the metal 055xprob and man that thing is built like a tank. It's really sturdy. I have the 488 rc2 ball head. It's quite sturdy too. Only downside is that the setup weighs a ton.