# How do I select a good mid-range tripod for my Nikon D90?

Tags: equipment-recommendation, nikon, nikon-d90, tripod

Planning to buy a tripod for my Nikon D90, but not sure which one to go with. Currently I am working only with my kit lens, but am planning to buy some more lenses in the near future, so while going for the tripod, I need to take care of this.

Can anyone suggest a good tripod in a medium budget range?

Update:
I want this for travelling/walking and no indoor work as i am only passion driven photographer.
Budget:something around 200USD

Comment: Will you be wanting to use this in a studio or when travelling / walking? Also, what is a medium budget for you?

Comment: Possible duplicate of more-generic question [What should I pay attention to when choosing a tripod?](http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/2505/what-should-i-pay-attention-to-when-choosing-a-tripod). That person had an entry-level Sony camera, which is a few pounds lighter, but answers should be in the same ballpark.

Comment: @MaynardCase:i have updated my post with additional information

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have said that you are a passion driven photographer(pretty much like me) I would suggest the Manfrotto 190XPROB. I wouldn't suggest anything heavier or bigger. This one isn't too big or flimsy and will work fine for years to come. It also fits your budget with a price tag of around $150.
If you buy a bigger one the chances are that you will tend to leave it at home.

Also note that there could be Silk tripods matching this profile but I can't comment since I haven't used one.

Answer (score 1):

I would look for a good heavy based Tripod for what ever budget you can afford. The extra weight will keep the tripod stable when wind blows, you can also look for one with a hook between the legs, this allows you to put weights on it (such as a camera bag) to keep it heavy.

I would look at brands such as Manfrotto or Giottos.

Comment: Although very heavy tripods tend to be left at home when walking or travelling.

Comment: True, so a Light weight one with a hook for your bag will be good to keep the wind from rocking it.

Comment: I think you want "sturdy" more than you want "heavy".

Comment: Yes that is part of it. If you get a good heavy based tripod and it has a wobbly leg it's no good at all.

Answer (score 0):

A midrange Manfrotto or Slik should serve you well for years.